# Tortoise and hare cycle detection algorithm using iterators in Python

Tags: python, iterator

Reading [the article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) in Wikipedia about cycle detection I came across a relatively small code snipped of Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm. I'll put it here to keep everything in one place:

```
def floyd(f, x0):
    # The main phase of the algorithm, finding a repetition x_mu = x_2mu
    # The hare moves twice as quickly as the tortoise
    tortoise = f(x0) # f(x0) is the element/node next to x0.
    hare = f(f(x0))
    while tortoise != hare:
        tortoise = f(tortoise)
        hare = f(f(hare))

    # at this point the start of the loop is equi-distant from current tortoise
    # position and x0, so hare moving in circle and tortoise (set to x0 )
    # moving towards circle, will intersect at the beginning of the circle.

    # Find the position of the first repetition of length mu
    # The hare and tortoise move at the same speeds
    mu = 0
    tortoise = x0
    while tortoise != hare:
        tortoise = f(tortoise)
        hare = f(hare)
        mu += 1

    # Find the length of the shortest cycle starting from x_mu
    # The hare moves while the tortoise stays still
    lam = 1
    hare = f(tortoise)
    while tortoise != hare:
        hare = f(hare)
        lam += 1

    return lam, mu
```

But then I decided, why not rewrite this algorithm using iterators.

The result wasn't as good as I had hoped it to be.

In some parts of the code I needed the values that the iterators have already returned. So I had keep the values apart from iterators themselves. And I introduced the class `animal` to keep them in one place.

To my mind, the code got very hefty and ugly. Here it is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import islice,cycle,chain


def detect_cycle(iterable):

    class animal(object):
        '''Holds the iterator and keeps the last value returned by the iterator'''
        def __init__(self,iterable):          
            self.it = iter(iterable)
            self.value = next(self.it) #get the first value

        def next(self):
            self.value = next(self.it)
            return self.value

        def __iter__(self):
            return self


    tortoise = animal(iterable)
    hare = animal(islice(iter(iterable),None,None,2))  #two steps at a time

    while True:
        if next(tortoise) == next(hare):
            break

    hare = tortoise #put hare in the place of tortoise
    tortoise = animal(iterable) #start tortoise from the very beginning
    mu = 0
    while True:
        if hare.value == tortoise.value:
            break
        next(hare)
        next(tortoise)
        mu += 1


    lamb = 0
    tortoise_val = tortoise.value #save the value of tortoise as the object is reassigned to hare
    hare = tortoise
    while True:
        next(hare)
        lamb += 1
        if hare.value == tortoise_val: #check AFTER the first step by hare
            break

    print('mu: {}'.format(mu))
    print('lamb: {}'.format(lamb))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    class iterable(object):
        '''Emulate the object returning iterators having cycles'''
        def __init__(self,beginning,cycling):
            '''
beginning: the beginning part with no cycles (its length corresponds to mu)
cycling: the part which will be cycling (its length corresponds to lamb)
'''
            self.beginning = beginning
            self.cycling = cycling

        def __iter__(self):
            return chain(iter(self.beginning),cycle(iter(self.cycling)))

    detect_cycle(iterable('1234','678'))
```

Is there anything that can be done to improve the code?
Is it the best that can be done using iterators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import islice,cycle,chain


def detect_cycle(iterable):

    class animal(object):
```

Putting classes inside function is usually not all that helpful. Also, the name doesn't really suggest what this class does.

```
        '''Holds the iterator and keeps the last value returned by the iterator'''
        def __init__(self,iterable):          
            self.it = iter(iterable)
```

I'd do something like iter, just because it isn't a really obvious abbreviation

```
            self.value = next(self.it) #get the first value

        def next(self):
            self.value = next(self.it)
            return self.value

        def __iter__(self):
            return self


    tortoise = animal(iterable)
    hare = animal(islice(iter(iterable),None,None,2))  #two steps at a time
```

You end up create two iterators from the same iterable. That might be problematic as you can't be sure those two iterators are independent.

```
    while True:
        if next(tortoise) == next(hare):
            break
```

You get most of the benefit of iterators when you can use for loops. In this case, I might use a for loop with itertools.izip.

```
    hare = tortoise #put hare in the place of tortoise
    tortoise = animal(iterable) #start tortoise from the very beginning
    mu = 0
    while True:
        if hare.value == tortoise.value:
            break
        next(hare)
        next(tortoise)
        mu += 1
```

You do this basic thing three times. You loop through both iterators, until they match. Write a function that takes the two iterators, does that and then returns the count of them.

```
    lamb = 0
    tortoise_val = tortoise.value #save the value of tortoise as the object is reassigned to hare
    hare = tortoise
    while True:
        next(hare)
        lamb += 1
        if hare.value == tortoise_val: #check AFTER the first step by hare
            break

    print('mu: {}'.format(mu))
    print('lamb: {}'.format(lamb))
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I have updated the code. Here it is: http://ideone.com/fYZ35. About the independence of iterators. I think it's very important. But I only came up with adding a warning in the description. Because I can't use `itertools.tee` since it'll defeat all the benefits of using this algorithm (since it'll be storing all the intermediary values). Also the usage of `chain(repeat((tortoise.val, hare.val),1)...` looks particularly ugly for me. But I haven't found any other way to add a single value to the chain.

Comment: I've made another version of the code which uses no class: http://ideone.com/fAlML All the logic which used to be covered in the code is no scattered around the code (the calculation of the first value follows a new iterator initialization always). Still, I don't like the code. The only conclusion I can draw from the experiment is that the original version of the code operating with indexes is more clear, short and straightforward.

Comment: Update 1: http://ideone.com/vJKiv Still curious, if it's the best way to add a single value before the main iterator: `chain(repeat(hare_val,1),hare)` (here `hare_val` is added befor all the other values returned by `hare` iterator).

Comment: Update 2: http://ideone.com/fgrwM Put all `while True:` code fragments into the function. Had to bring back the holding iterator class since otherwise I would have to return the current values of the iterator from that function somehow which will make the code completely cumbersome.

Comment: @ovgolovin, instead of `repeat(hare_val, 1)` just use `[hare_val]`. What if `consume_iterator...` returned the matching value as well as the count? I think then you can get rid of keeping iterator.

Comment: Thank you! My initial idea to use itertools wasn't that good definitely.